# Haskell CPS: How to implement map and filter functions using Cont monad?

Tags: haskell, dictionary, filter, continuation-passing

I've been trying to learn CPS, seems I didn't really get my head around it, could you implement basic filter and map using Cont monad?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. I think a good first step would be to ignore the Cont monad itself and just write some code in CPS using continuations explicitly.

Comment: There are some good papers here that might be useful: http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dfried/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this, let's first start without the monad since CPS isn't dependent on it.

```
cpsMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> ([b] -> r) -> r
cpsMap f (a:as) c = cpsMap f as (c.(f a:))
cpsMap  _ []    c = c []

map' f xs = cpsMap f xs id
```

And now the `Cont` monad is trivial

```
contMap :: (a -> b) -> [a] ->  Cont r [b]
contMap f (a:as) = contMap f as >>= return . (f a :)
contMap _ [] = return []

map'' f xs = runCont (contMap f xs) id
```

The only difference here is we don't have to touch the continuations ourselves, `return` pipes the value into it for us.

To visualize it let's trace it with `map'' (+1) [1..3]`

```
as      | c
[1,2,3] | id
[2,3]   | id . (2 :)
[3]     | id . (2 :) . (3 :)
[]      | id . (2 :) . (3 :) . (4 :)
id . (2 :) . (3 :) . (4 :) $ []
[2, 3, 4]
```

Notice that all `Cont` does is wrap the `([b] -> r) -> r` part of our code under a newtype. Really we can think of `Cont` as

```
newtype Cont r a = Cont ((a -> r) -> r)
```

I'll leave implementing filter to you :)

Comment: No problem, if this answers your question, please tick the green check box to mark the question as answered

Comment: The `cpsMap` function uses CPS style for the map function itself, but not for calling `f`.  If you really want CPS you need to change the type of `f` as well.

Comment: How exactly should it be changed?

Comment: I do not find it particularly helpful that you arbitrarily restrict the result type of `cpsMap` and `contMap` to `[b]`.

Comment: @kosmikus Fair enough, I thought that it would make it a bit clearer that it was a `map`, I've edited it though